# How to sequentially run promises with error handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I need to call 3 requests in sequence, all of them with 3 resolutions

- if request is 200 and response is ok, call another request
- if request is 200, but response is bad, do something
- if request is not successful, do something else

Happy path would look like this:

```
const firstCallResponse = await this.service1.call1();
if (firstCallResponse) {
  const secondCallResponse = await this.service2.call2();
  if (secondCallResponse) {
    const thirdCallResponse = await this.service3.call3();
    if (thirdCallResponse) {
      console.log('sequence finished successfully);
    }
  }
}
```

And it doesn't look that bad, but if I'll try to add those two fallbacks for every request, the code will become very messy.

```
try {
  const firstCallResponse = await this.service1.call1();
  if (firstCallResponse) {
    try {
      const secondCallResponse = await this.service2.call2();
      if (secondCallResponse) {
        try {
          const thirdCallResponse = await this.service3.call3();
          if (thirdCallResponse) {
            console.log('sequence finished successfully');
          } else {
            console.log('do something, as third call response is not ok');
          }
        } catch {
          console.log('do something as third call failed');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('do something, as second call response is not ok');
      }
    } catch {
      console.log('do something as second call failed');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('do something, as first call response is not ok');
  }
} catch {
  console.log('do something as first call failed');
}
```

Is there a way to make this code more readable or elegant? The code above would work, but it doesn't look good and it's extremely hard to read. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you show real code, including what the fallback code actually is, then we could offer you better ways to solve your actual programming problem.  Usually, you don't need a separate fallback for every single `await` or you can put the fallback into a shared function so you can surround multiple `await`  calls with a single `try/catch` and then the code cleans up quite nicely.  Hard to answer more specifically when you only show pseudo-code, not real code.

Comment: If you really need to "*do something*" different for each failed call, then this is what your code is going to look like. Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can wrap more than one promise with `try`/`catch` if you want to do the same thing when they fail. Also accept argument in catch blocks since they can tell you where error originated / more info about it aka

```
try {
  // await promise
} catch (errorName) {
  // handle error
}
```

Other than that main thing I would recommend is reversing your logic with checking the results what to do next and adding `return` statements.

```
try {
  const firstCallResponse = await this.service1.call1();
  if (!firstCallResponse) {
    console.log('do something as first call failed');
    return;
  }

  const secondCallResponse = await this.service2.call2();
  if (!secondCallResponse) {
    console.log('do something as second call failed');
    return;
  }

  // ...
  // if no errors do something with all results
} catch {
  console.log('do something as first call failed');
}
```

Another tip I would like to add for end is if your second call does not require anything from results of first call you can group them all in one promise with

```
await Promise.all([
  this.service1.call1(),
  this.service2.call2()
])
```